# Set variable outside AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to create an ajax function that returns a specific string from a page, and then sets it in the class I created. However, when I attempt to call `this.setGlideUser` within the ajax success parameter, it tells me that the

```
object has no function setUserGlide.
```

And when I attempt to call `this.setUserGlide` outside of the success parameter, and then look at the value of `_glideUser`, `_glideUser` is undefined. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
function main()
{
    this.start = true;
}

main.prototype.load = function()
{
    var _glideUser;
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/home',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data)
        {
            // Truncated
            _glideUser = unescape(data).match(pattern);
        }
    });
    this.setGlideUser(_glideUser);
    return 1;
}

main.prototype.setGlideUser(user)
{
    return this._glideUser = user;
}

main.prototype.getGlideUser()
{
    return this._glideUser;
}

var _main = new main();
_main.load();
// check that the ajax has completely loaded
_main.getGlideUser(); // returns undefined
```

I can't think of a way to set the `_glideUser` variable within the main class from the Ajax success function. I would like to get the value of `_glideUser` within another function, to do things with it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `this._glideUser`, because `_glideUser` is local to your `load` function. Instead of declaring `var _glideUser` inside `load`, set it as a public property from the constructor:

```
function main()
{
    this.start = true;
    this._glideUser = null;
}
```

(Your first call to `setGlideUser` would actually create such a property, but isn't it confusing to have both?)

Also, as others mentioned, you're trying to `setGlideUser` *before* your ajax operation completed. You need to do that from the `success` callback:

```
main.prototype.load = function()
{
    var that = this;
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/home',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data)
        {
            that.setGlideUser(unescape(data).match(pattern));
        }
    });
    return 1; // what's the point?
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you! I didn't think to set a `var that = this;` declaration, but that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite familiar with jQuery but that ajax request is probably asynchronous, so you have to call setGlideUser from inside the ajax success call, just add a reference variable to your instance and call it from there:

```
var self = this;
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/home',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data)
    {
        self.setGlideUser(unescape(data).match(pattern));
    }
});
```

And just a quick tip for you is that you can have getters and setters in js like this:

```
main.prototype.__defineSetter__("glideUser", function(value)
{
    this._glideUser = value;
});

main.prototype.__defineGetter__("glideUser", function()
{
    return this._glideUser;
});
```

Edit:
Actually, see comments for that stuff

Comment: It's nice that you're suggesting actual accessor properties, but `__defineGetter__`/`__defineSetter__` are both non-standard and deprecated. The standard (ES5) way to do that is with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out, I'm a little outdated on javascript

Answer (score 0):

`success` is not invoked until the request returns.  It is *asynchronous*.  You need to invoke the method within success itself, when the data value is available.

```
main.prototype.load = function()
{
    var _glideUser, that = this;
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/home',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data)
        {
            // Truncated
            var = _glideUser = unescape(data).match(pattern);
            that.setGlideUser(_glideUser);
        }
    });
    // this.setGlideUser(_glideUser); this is incorrect
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyword **this** means the current scope, which is in this (pun intended) case the ajax object. You need a reference to the outer this object, by assigning **me** to **this** in the outer object.

```
main.prototype.load = function()
 {
    var _glideUser;
    var me = this;
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/home',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data)
        {
            // Truncated
            _glideUser = unescape(data).match(pattern);
            me.setGlideUser(_glideUser);
        }
    });
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> attempt to call this.setGlideUser within the ajax success parameter

That was correct. However, the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the success method points to the jqXHR object and not to your `main` instance; you will need to dereference it:

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
    url: '/home',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        _glideUser = unescape(data).match(pattern);
        that.setGlideUser(_glideUser);
    }
});
```